# How to modify PdfPCell so that you can remove a part of a border (e.g BOTTOM, TOP, LEFT)?

Tags: java, border, itext

Here an example of my code:

```
PdfPCell row6cell_1 = new PdfPCell(row6Par_1);            
row6cell_1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);  
row6cell_1.setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT);  
row6cell_1.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);  
row6cell_1.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);  
row6cell_1.setBorderWidth(1.0f);
```

I want to modify the border of the cell so that the RIGHT border line of the cell will not appear. Anyone can help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:
This is for removing the bottom border only.

```
Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("001"));
Cell.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.LEFT);
```

Comment: One thing to remember is that a neighbor cell's border is not affected by this. So if you want to remove a top-border for a cell in the middle; you need to remove the bottom-border on the cell above to get the effect.

Answer (score 2):

cell.DisableBorderSide(1);//(1-Top,2-Bottom,3-left and 4-Right border) Enjoy it for removing part of cell's border..

Answer (score 1):

Pappoo Singh answer is good but for me works:
`cell.DisableBorderSide(x)`
where x can be:

x - 1 //top

x - 2 //bottom

x - 4 //left

x - 8 //right